# Prefix column with zeroes in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a new attribute x with concatenation of attributes a + b + c. If the total length of x is less than 10, then I want to prefix only attribute c with 0. How can I do this?

```
val x = when length(concat($"a", $"b", $"c")) < 10, 
        concat($"a", $"b", lpad($"c", 10, '0'))
       .otherwise(concat($"a", $"b", $"c"))
```

The above wont work as column c will be prefixed with 0's until length 10, whereas I want the overall length after concat to be 10. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an sql expression for the `lpad`:

```scala
val df =Seq(("aaa","bbb","cccc"),
  ("a","b","c"),
  ("a","b","1234567890123"),
  ("a","b","")).toDF("a","b","c")

df.withColumn("x", when(length(concat($"a",$"b",$"c")) < 10,
  concat($"a", $"b", expr("lpad(c, 10 - char_length(a) - char_length(b), '0')")))
  .otherwise(concat($"a",$"b",$"c")))
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+-------------+---------------+
|  a|  b|            c|              x|
+---+---+-------------+---------------+
|aaa|bbb|         cccc|     aaabbbcccc|
|  a|  b|            c|     ab0000000c|
|  a|  b|1234567890123|ab1234567890123|
|  a|  b|             |     ab00000000|
+---+---+-------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically what you want is the following:

```scala
val ab = concat($"a", $"b")
val x = concat(ab, lpad($"c", lit(10) - length(ab), lit("0")))
//                            ^ Not possible        ^ Not possible
```

Unfortunately this isn't possible because the Spark Scala `lpad` function has the signature `str: Column, len: Int, pad: String` and you can't provide `Column` objects as the `len` and `pad` parameters.

If you examine the underlying Catalyst `StringLPad` expression type, it doesn't require constants for the `len` and `pad` parameters. This means we can define our own version of `lpad` that allows for Column values passed as `len` and `pad` so that the length and the length and padding string can be variable for each row.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StringLPad

def lpad_var(str: Column, len: Column, pad: Column) =
 new Column(StringLPad(str.expr, len.expr, pad.expr))

val ab = concat($"a", $"b")
val x = concat(ab, lpad_var($"c", lit(10) - length(ab), lit("0")))
```

Here is an example output with some edge cases:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "bb", "c"),
  ("aa", "bbb", "c"),
  ("", "", "")
).toDF("a", "b", "c")

df.select(x.as("x")).show()
// +----------+
// |         x|
// +----------+
// |abb000000c|
// |aabbb0000c|
// |0000000000|
// +----------+
```